# Как узнать файл диска зная файл раздела в линукс

Tags: linux, bash

Как найти диск содержащий известный раздел?

Например знаю UUID, по нему найду `/dev/sda1` - как узнать путь `/dev/sda` кроме удаления циферки в конце?

Имя файла раздела может быть не только `sdX1`, но и `/dev/nvme0n1p1` или `/dev/loop1p1`...

Comment: `readlink -f /dev/disk/by-uuid/<UUID>` сойдёт?

Comment: не, это через blkid и так находится. нудно найти диск зная его раздел

Comment: `lsblk -n -i /dev/sda2 --output PKNAME` - как вариант проверить работу

Comment: @PotroNik то что нужно

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Предлагаю использовать инструмент `lsblk`

`-n` - не выводит шапку таблицы
`-i` - принимает указание раздела, добавляем необходимы раздел после ключа `/dev/s...`
`--output` - самостоятельное построение таблицы вывода
`PKNAME` - имя родительского устройства

В итоге выполняем команду:

```
lsblk -n -i /dev/sda2 --output PKNAME
```

вывод:

```
sda
```